# Ориентация для UIViewController созданного через код

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли заблокировать смену ориентации экрана (или сделать только портретную) при создании UIViewController таким образом:

```
promowindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
promocont = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[promowindow setRootViewController:promocont];
```

Доступа к настройкам главного контроллера нет.

Comment: Попробуйте так: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26831726/608343

Comment: Увы, к UIViewController.m, AppDelegate.m и тд нет доступа. Они зашит в архиве движка. Надежда на какой-нибудь метод, который можно применить к вновь созданному контроллеру и тем самым задать или ограничить ориентацию.

Answer (score 1):

Можна добавить такой метод:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: А если к UIViewController.m нет доступа? Он зашит в архиве движка? Нельзя ли здесь и сейчас, при создании контроллера, задать ему ориентацию?

Comment: NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];

Answer (score 0):

Можно реализовать переопределение методов в runtime, то есть переопределить стандартный метод, который делает переворот экрана.

Так же можно сделать метод в том самом View Controller и вызывать его в init